# ScrollPosition is not set to top when navigating to other pages

Tags: typescript, vue.js, router, quasar, scroll-position

The web page is designed in master-slave fashion. The master has tabs (left pane) which when clicked displays the respective page in the slave (right pane). for eg. master has three two tabs "architecture and templates" in which architecture is displayed by default. The user can navigate between these two pages(loaded by slave) using the tabs in the left pane(loaded by master).

Now when the user scrolls to some position in the architecture page and navigates to templates page the scroll position is not set to top. However the scrollbehavior is set in the router file.

```
const createRouter = () =>
  new VueRouter({
     scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
     routes:[
     //has all the routes
     ]
});
```

When a breakpoint is set near scrollBehavior and observed, the line is hit whenever there is a navigation but the scrollposition is not set to top when navigating from architecture to templates page.

However when scrolling to certain position in templates page and navigating to architecture page the page is set to top.

Also tried writing window.scrollTo(0, 0); function inside mounted() in templates.ts. Even that is hit but the page is not set to top.

Could someone explain why this is happening. I tried almost every possible solution listed in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem in vue. If you want to scroll on top, you will need to use this hack. instead of `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` use it inside a setTimeout with little timeout time. 
`settimeout(()=>{ window.scrollTo(0, 0); }, 10)` 
Hope This helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you. However even after setting a timeout the window.scrollTo(0, 0) has no effect on the page. I even tried increasing the timeout but it is not working.

Comment: Test this my friend: `document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: I don't know what's wrong. Even this line was executed but the page is not set to top.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js file use this code. Your problem will be solved. This is for ReactJs project.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const { pathname } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, [pathname]);
```